# Use React to build a todo-list, but it has unexpected results

Tags: reactjs

This is my practice demo, it's about todo list.
You can see, when I confirm a task. It's will be gone, but next task state is checked.

How can I fix? Thanks in advance.

[image]

code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import InpuText from './component/InpuText';

class Note extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputdata: 'no data',
      noteData: ''
    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('note')) {
      this.setState({
        noteData: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('note')).details
      })
    }
  }
  getInputValue(getValue) {
    this.setState({
      inputdata: getValue
    })
    if(localStorage.getItem('note')) {
      this.state.noteData.push({
        text: getValue
      })
      let note = {
        details: this.state.noteData
      }
      localStorage.setItem('note', JSON.stringify(note));
    }else {
      let note = {
        details: []
      }
      note.details.push({
        text: getValue
      })
      this.setState({
        noteData: note.details
      })
      localStorage.setItem('note', JSON.stringify(note));
    }
  }
  finish(index, e) {
    console.log(e.target.checked)
    if(e.target.checked === true) {
      this.state.noteData.splice(index, 1)
      this.setState({
        noteData: this.state.noteData
      })
      let note = {
        details: this.state.noteData
      }
      localStorage.setItem('note', JSON.stringify(note));
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        notepad
        <InpuText getInputValue={this.getInputValue.bind(this)}/>
        {/* <p>input data:{this.state.inputdata}</p> */}
        <div>todo</div>
        {
          this.state.noteData
          ?
            <ul>
              {this.state.noteData.map((notes, i)=>(
                <li key={i}>
                  {i}:{notes.text}
                  <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.finish.bind(this, i)}/>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          :
            <p>no task</p>
        }
        <div>done</div>
        <ul>
          <li>123</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Note;
```

finish() is handle Array to remove the finish task.

Comment: without seeing your code how anyone can help you. paste the code also

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) firstly to learn how to ask, edit your answer and then we are going to be happy helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to a couple of things:

- You use the item's index (i) as the react key. This is bad practice, because the key is not stable. As an example, consider you have three items - their keys would be 0,1,2. Then you mark the middle one as completed, rendering only two items with keys 0 and 1. However these items had keys 0 and 2 respectively during the last render, which generally means that the reconciliation will be messed up. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html for details. In short, the keys need to stay the same between renders.
- You don't specify any value for the checkbox, therefore it is uncontrolled (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html), meaning that it gets checked/unchecked freely as you click on it.

These two points together lead to the behavior that you see: you click the item, it gets checked (since the input is uncontrolled), then in the following render it gets reconciled with the wrong item (because of the index-based key).

To fix this, don't use collection index as key, use some immutable unique ID from the actual items (if there is no ID, add one). Also, set the checkboxes value prop rather than leaving them uncontrolled. You could e.g. add an `isComplete` property to every item in the model and set the checkbox value prop to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will fix it!